# How can i send one query result (via variable) into an other query

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

What I want is to include the result of sub variable into another query.

```
 $sub = DB::table('chef_food_ethics')->
 select(DB::raw('count(id) as fCount'))
 ->where('chef_food_ethics.food_ethic_id',
 '=','food_ethic_managers.food_ethic_id')
 ->toSql();
```

Is it possible to include it like that?

```
 $r = DB::table('food_ethic_managers')where
 ('food_ethic_managers.manager_id','=',$id)
 ->leftJoin('staff','food_ethic_managers.food_ethic_id'
  ,'=','staff.id')
 ->leftJoin('regions','staff.region_id','=','regions.id')
 ->with($sub)
 ->get();
```

Comment: I tried 
$r = DB::table('food_ethic_managers')where
 ('food_ethic_managers.manager_id','=',$id)
 ->leftJoin('staff','food_ethic_managers.food_ethic_id'
  ,'=','staff.id')
 ->leftJoin('regions','staff.region_id','=','regions.id')
 ->union($sub)
 ->get();
but it is giving me **Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns **

Comment: It could be possible with a union. Make sure the number of columns for $sub and $r are the same

Comment: @JackPoint or there's no other way??

Comment: laravel eloquent ORM  you can do it.

Comment: how can i do nested query with orm?? @PratikMehta